# Sending letter by letter to LCD, however the LCD knows the full string?

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, lcd, ethernet-shield

I think this is my last post about this specific project, but I got a really weird curveball right now

I managed to do the webpage I wanted, and pass the string along. Now, when a LED lights up, it sends the corresponding letter to the LCD.

The problem now is that somehow, when I send a long string, the LCD somehow "knows" and display the overflow on the second row, which makes no sense to me. All I can think of is that the Ethernet Shield is using the same connections as my I2C that connects to the LCD.

That being said, here is my code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#define latchPin 5
#define clockPin 7
#define dataPin 6

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED }; 
EthernetServer server(80);
String text; 
char readHttp[100];
int i;
boolean temtexto;
char lcdtext[16];
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  for (int i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
    if (i != 4) {
      pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
    }
   }
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
  lcd.init();
  lcd.setBacklight(HIGH);
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("INICIANDO");
  Serial.println("Iniciando");
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(1,0);
    lcd.print("FALHA AO PEGAR");
    Serial.println("FALHA");
    lcd.setCursor(7,1);
    lcd.print("IP");
    delay(5000);
    return;
  }

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("PRONTO");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(Ethernet.localIP());
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  server.begin();
  brilho(255);
  inicializationEffect();
}

void loop(){
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        lcd.setBacklight(LOW);
        lcd.clear();
        char c = client.read();
        if (c == ';') { temtexto = false; readHttp[i] = '\n';}
        if (temtexto) {
          if(i < 100) {
            readHttp[i] = toupper(c);
            i++;
          } 
        }
        if (c == '?') { temtexto = true; }
        if (c == '\n') {
          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); // Envia nova pagina
          client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
          client.println("Connection: close"); 
          client.println();
          client.println("<HTML>");
          client.println("<HEAD>");
          client.println("<TITLE>Parede Stranger Things</TITLE>");
          client.println("</HEAD>");
          client.println("<BODY>");
          client.println("<H1>Qual texto deseja enviar?</H1>");
          client.println("<input type=text id=texto style=width:295px  maxlength=50><br>");
          client.println("<input type=submit value='Enviar' style=width:150px;height:45px onClick=location.href='/?'+document.getElementById('texto').value+';'>");
          client.println("</BODY>");
          client.println("</HTML>");
          client.println("<string>");

          
          client.println("</string>");          
          delay(1);
          client.stop();
          char *leader = readHttp;
          char *follower = leader;
          
          // While we're not at the end of the string (current character not NULL)
          while (*leader) {
              // Check to see if the current character is a %
              if (*leader == '%') {
          
                  // Grab the next two characters and move leader forwards
                  leader++;
                  char high = *leader;
                  leader++;
                  char low = *leader;
          
                  // Convert ASCII 0-9A-F to a value 0-15
                  if (high > 0x39) high -= 7;
                  high &= 0x0f;
          
                  // Same again for the low byte:
                  if (low > 0x39) low -= 7;
                  low &= 0x0f;
          
                  // Combine the two into a single byte and store in follower:
                  *follower = (high << 4) | low;
              } else {
                  // All other characters copy verbatim
                  *follower = *leader;
              }
          
              // Move both pointers to the next character:
              leader++;
              follower++;
          }
          // Terminate the new string with a NULL character to trim it off
          *follower = 0;
          lcd.clear();
          executeEffect(readHttp);
          memset(readHttp, 0, sizeof readHttp);
          i = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}




void lineActivation(int line, int keepalive) {
  if (keepalive == 0) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= 4; i++) {
      if (i == 4) { i = 8; } //porta 4 usada pelo SD do Ethernet
      digitalWrite(i, LOW);
    }
  }
  if (line >= 1 && line <=3){
    if (line == 3) { line = 7; } //porta 4 usada pelo SD do Ethernet
    digitalWrite(line+1, HIGH); //coloca a linha 1 em estado lógico alto
  }
}

void activateLetter(char letter, int on, int off) {
  int lt;
  lt = (((int)letter - 64) % 9);
  if (((int)letter - 64) > 8) {
    lt = lt + 1;
  }
  if (on) {
    callCol(1<<lt-1);
    delay(on);
  }
  if (off) {
    callCol(0);
    delay(off);
  }
}

void callCol(int col){
  digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
  shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, highByte(col));
  shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, lowByte(col));
  digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
}

void executeEffect(char text[]) {
  if (strlen(text) > 0) {
    brilho(255);
    lcd.setBacklight(HIGH);
    memset(lcdtext, ' ', sizeof lcdtext);  
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) {
    if (text[i] == ' ') {
      lcdScreen(' ');
      delay(1000);
    } else if (((int)text[i] < -58 && (int)text[i] > -65) || ((int)text[i] < -28 && (int)text[i] > -33)) {
      text[i] = 'A';
    } else if (((int)text[i] < -47 && (int)text[i] > -41) || ((int)text[i] < -9 && (int)text[i] > -14)) {
      text[i] = 'O';
    } else if (((int)text[i] < -52 && (int)text[i] > -57) || ((int)text[i] < -20 && (int)text[i] > -25)) {
      text[i] = 'E';
    } else if (((int)text[i] < -49 && (int)text[i] > -53) || ((int)text[i] < -16 && (int)text[i] > -21)) {
      text[i] = 'I';
    } else if (((int)text[i] < -35 && (int)text[i] > -40) || ((int)text[i] < -3 && (int)text[i] > -8)) {
      text[i] = 'U';
    } else if (((int)text[i] == -25 || (int)text[i] == -57)) {
      text[i] = 'C';
    }
    if ((int)text[i] < 65 or (int)text[i] > 90) {
    } else {
      lineActivation(int(((int)text[i] - 64) / 9) + 1, 0);
      //Serial.println(text[i]);
      lcdScreen(text[i]);
      activateLetter(text[i], 1000, 200);
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
    lcdScreen(' ');
    delay(500);
  }
  lcd.setBacklight(LOW);
  lcd.clear();
}

void lcdScreen(char ltc) {
  Serial.println(ltc);
  memcpy(lcdtext, &lcdtext[1], sizeof(lcdtext) - sizeof(char));
  lcdtext[15] =  ltc;
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print(lcdtext);
}

void inicializationEffect() {
  Serial.println("LineByLine");
  for (int i = 1; i < 27; i++) {
    lineActivation(int(i / 9) + 1, 0);//ativa a linha
    activateLetter(char(64 + i), 100, 10); //ativa a letra
  }
}

void waveEffect() {
  Serial.println("Wave");
  for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    lineActivation(i, 1);//ativa a linha
  }
  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    activateLetter(char(72 + i), 100, 0);
  }

  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    activateLetter(char(72 + i), 0, 100);
  }
  lineActivation(0, 0);
}

void blink() {
  Serial.println("Blink");
  callCol(511);
  lineActivation(1,1);
  lineActivation(2,1);
  lineActivation(3,1);
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
    brilho(i);
    delay(1);
  }
  delay(100);
  for (int i = 255; i >= 0; i--){
    brilho(i);
    delay(1);
  }
}

void brilho(byte brt) {
  analogWrite(9, 255-brt);
}
```

I am using a W5100 Ethernet Shield, a I2C to LCD adapter and a 16x2 LCD. The I2C is connected to the pins A4(SDA) and A5(SCL).

Here is a picture of how the LCD appears when I send "This is a really long string":

[image]

On the first line the text scrolls, one character at a time, as intended. However, on the second line there is an overflow of the text that, as far as I can tell, I never sent to the LCD in the first place. Even if I try to lcd.clear() after every character sent, it still persists with the end of the string on the second line.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're seeing is the result of:

```
lcd.print(lcdtext);
```

and the fact that lcdtext is not null-terminated.  `print()` is expecting
a string, that is some sequence of zero or more non-'\0' characters followed by a `'\0'` character.  Not having null-terminated it yourself, in practice it will continue reading memory after your the location of lcdtext in memory until it finds a `'\0'`.  Somewhere in there it is probably finding the extra character(s) that you're seeing.

You could make a point of having `'\0'` at the end of it always, making lcdtext one character larger if necessary in order to do that.  Or you could:

```
lcd.write(lcdtext, sizeof lcdtext);
```

In this form with the length/size as a second argument, `write` doesn't expect a string, just an arbitrary chunk of characters whether they contain `'\0'` or not and knows to stop at whatever count of characters was specified.

As an aside `memmove` should be used rather than `memcpy` when the input and output destinations overlap.  What happens with `memcpy` when they do overlap is undefined:

```
memmove(lcdtext, &lcdtext[1], sizeof(lcdtext) - 1);
```

`memmove` is outwardly the same thing, only designed for this scenario.  The difference between them is a matter of which optimizations are enabled by the knowledge that the source and destination may or may not overlap. It may not be a source of a problem on your current platform, depending on how memcpy was written, but it may later or when you switch platforms.

Comment: I replaced memcpy with memmove and it worked the same way as before. The lcd.write is not a function on <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>, which is the library I am using for I2C to communicate with led. Adding a '\0' to the end just removed the 4 lines at the end. The RING still appeared

Comment: @Feeds, I'm not surprised `memmove()` made no difference on an AVR.  I am sort of surprised you're not able to use that form of `write()` though, since it is part of the `Print` class which provides `print()` and `println()` among others.  Do you have a link to the exact rendition of LiquidCrystal_I2C library you're using?

Comment: Now that I think about it, the problem may reside on the lcdtext not being a string, but a char array. The library I am using is the one on sketch https://github.com/johnrickman/LiquidCrystal_I2C, version 1.1.2

Comment: At https://github.com/johnrickman/LiquidCrystal_I2C/blob/master/LiquidCrystal_I2C.h#L55 you can see where Print inherited.  At https://github.com/johnrickman/LiquidCrystal_I2C/blob/master/LiquidCrystal_I2C.cpp#L10 single character write() is implemented.  https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/1.8.3/cores/arduino/Print.cpp#L34 where the default implementation is for the two-parameter version of write() mentioned uses the single character write().

Comment: In other words, it should work fine.  If that's a sticking point, take some time with it and if still stuck maybe start a new question with a cut-down code example asking about that one aspect.

Comment: I am away from my arduino right now, but I will test as soon as I get home to report my findings. I am still weirded out how the LCD works

Answer (score 0):

Huh, I kinda solved it, but I still dont get it how the `lcdtext` was getting the full string.

I replaced the lcdScreen function with this:

```
void lcdScreen(char ltc) {
  Serial.println(ltc);
  Serial.print(lcdtext);
  memmove(lcdtext, &lcdtext[1], sizeof(lcdtext) - 1);
  lcdtext[15] =  ltc;
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
    lcd.print(lcdtext[i]);
  }
}
```

It works, but I still dont understand why I had the full text when I am just calling this function with a single char each time